# Communicating between mysql and objective c (receiving data)

Tags: php, ios, mysql, objective-c, json

I am communicating between php, mysql, and objective c. I am using Json to receive data from the php file. The problem is that I am only receiving the first piece of data from the php file. I tried to create a for loop but that only printed the first received data 5 times (This is the number of data in the database). I am not sure what to do please help. Below is my code:

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{
    NSError *error;

    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptionserror:&error];
}

-(void) start{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getData:data];

    //NSLog(@"Test:", data);

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //int *num = [json count];

    for(NSString* key in info){
        NSLog([info objectForKey:@"title"]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the `key` variable inside the `for` loop?

Comment: and your `indexPath` variable is nil when you use it...
what do you get from `NSLog("%@", json);`?

Comment: Ill try that and let you know

Comment: When i do that it prints out everything In the database, but it is in a weird format:

Comment: body = testing;
    date = "2015-04-26";
    id = 20;
    tags = tag1;
    title = title1;
}
It looks like this. I am trying to only get the title, and body to print and not in a weird format tike this

Comment: Is all of the data you want to be receiving in iOS visible at the endpoint?

Comment: What do u mean by that? All of the data i am trying to receive, i can but the format is not how i want it