# Create a textview in a for loop in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, uitextview

I am retrieving data from a mysql database and want to display it in a textview. So, I created a for loop for each piece of data. The problem is it only creates one textview and therefore only displays the first piece of retrieved data. My code is below:

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data {
    NSError *error;
    json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
}

-(void) start {
    //NSLog(@"%lu", (unsigned long)[json count]);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getData:data];

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;
    NSDictionary *info = [json objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++)
    {
        //NSLog(@"%@", json);

        UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
        myTextView.text = [info objectForKey:@"title"];
        [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
        [myTextView sizeToFit];
    }
}
```

Comment: It would seem that `json` only has one object in it.

Comment: it has 5 because when i do an NSLog it prints 5 and when i do an NSLog of json, it also prints 5 things

Comment: Give each text view a different frame. At the moment you create them all with the same frame so you can only see the last one.

Comment: A UITableview would probably be a better idea

Comment: Ok well, when I print the Json count it returns 0. That doesn't make sense because when i do the following: NSLog(@"%@", json); It returns 5 different things

Comment: If you want better help you need to add more code to your question showing how `json` is populated and show the output of logging `json`.

Comment: Because of the way the application is supposed to look, I am trying to avoid a UITableView.

Comment: Ok Ill edit my question

Comment: I am not sure about your idea but how your `indexPath` variable is being set up. It seems like it would always be `nil`

Comment: This is the same bad code from your previous question. Why do you leave `indexPath` initialized? Where is the log of `json`? Why don't you do anything with `info`?

Comment: Honestly, I am not sure what I am supposed to do with info to not keep it nil

Comment: Here is the log for NSLog(@"%@", json):

Comment: possible duplicate of [Communicating between mysql and objective c (receiving data)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881471/communicating-between-mysql-and-objective-c-receiving-data)

Comment: You should have used `for (NSDictionary* info in json) {....}` and so on. No `indexPath` is required. Also you should have used `initWithFrame` for your text views. `init` is not a designated initializer for text view and other `UIView` subclasses.

Comment: (
        {
        body = test;
        date = "2015-04-26";
        id = 19;
        tags = tag2;
        title = "test 2";
    },
        {
        body = this is a test;
        date = "2015-04-26";
        id = 18;
        tags = tag3;
        title = "test1";
    },
        {
        body = "How do you use all 3 of these?";
        date = "2015-04-26";
        id = 17;
        tags = tag1;
        title = "testt";
    })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json is an array and info is one dictionary in json.

You are looping five times over json but printing the same info. You need:

```
int yPos = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < [json count]; i++)
{
    //NSLog(@"%@", json);
    info = [json objectAtIndex:i];
    UITextView *myTextView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
    myTextView.text = [info objectForKey:@"title"];
    [self.view addSubview:myTextView];
    [myTextView sizeToFit];
    yPos += myTextView.frame.size.height;
    myTextView.frame = CGRectMake(0, yPos, myTextView.frame.size.width, myTextView.frame.size.height);

}
```

Comment: Also, how could I create a frame for each textview?

Comment: Currently It prints all of the data on top of each other

Comment: It have updated my answer. I think that [myTextView sizeToFit] should create an appropriate size and height for your textview but I am not too sure since a textview is scrollable. If the user is not supposed to be able to edit it you might be better off with a UILabel though

Comment: Also if the text is supposed to display two [info objectForKey:@""] things then how would I add the second. Would i just add a comma and add it?

Comment: Concatenate the strings in the way you want. I.e create a NSString *text = [[info objectForKey:@"title"] stringByAppendingString:[info objectForKey:@"body"]]; and set the textview text to that. There are many ways to concatenate a string so if you want something more advanced, have a look at the NSString [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/)